# adobe-indesign TOC generate subhead2 first before subhead1

Tags: adobe-indesign, table-of-contents

I am creating a document using Adobe InDesign and for some reason  when creating the table of content the subhead2 content is printed before the subhead1 content.

For example on the document I have

```
Chapter 1 - Overview
Chapter 2 - Introduction
    System Requirements
    Known Issues
```

The table of content is generated as follows:

[image]

If someone could explain to me what I am doing wrong it would be great!

Thank you!

ps. This is the document. The left side is page 3 and the right is page 4. "System Requirements", "Known Issues" and "Limitations" are all subhead2.
"Chapter 2 - Introduction" is subhead1.

[image]

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the document and where the styles are applied.

Comment: I remember seeing this once in one of my documents, don't remember how i fixed it, certainly couldn't tell by just looking at a picture.

Comment: @AndrewH I included a screenshot of the document.

Comment: @Lucian Let me know if you remember how you fixed your problem !

Comment: Are all the text frames threaded? How big are they? Could you replace the screen shot with one in normal view mode instead of preview mode? The TOC bases the order of headers on text frame locations on the page, vertical and horizontal. In order to see why it may be getting them in an unexpected order, we’d need to be able to see the elements on the page properly.